# Multiple Threads in kafka 0.10

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api

in kafka 0.8.2, we can explicitly defined how many threads to deal with multi-partitions, but in kafka 0.10, as example:

```
for (TopicPartition partition : records.partitions()) { //按partition处理
    List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> partitionRecords = records.records(partition); //取出partition对应的Records
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : partitionRecords) {
        System.out.printf("partition = %d, offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s",record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
     }
     // consumer.commitSync();
     long lastOffset = partitionRecords.get(partitionRecords.size() - 1).offset(); //取出last offset
     consumer.commitSync(Collections.singletonMap(partition, new OffsetAndMetadata(lastOffset + 1))); //独立的sync每个partition的offset
 }
```

in this way, how does it handle multi-partitions? single thread or else?

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html For multi threaded use case, you can just start you program multiple times (or start multiple thread with the same logic each using it's own `KafkaConsumer` instance.

Comment: Thanks,  Matthias J. Sax! Good documentation!